# Exmor RS. What value does it add to an 1" sensor?

Tags: sensor, sony

Recently, new versions of Sony P&S cameras (DSC-RX10 II, DSC-RX100 IV) have emerged. They feature new 1" stacked CMOS image sensor called [Exmor RS](http://www.sony.net/SonyInfo/News/Press/201411/14-112E/).
I understand that this technology increases the photoreceptor area for a pixel of the same size, thus reducing noise even more. (Previous version [Exmor R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exmor) was already a [back-illuminated sensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-illuminated_sensor) that already reduced read noise.)
This kind of sensor is a "port" from smartphone camera world with tiny sensor sizes where moving circuity into another layer probably made a significant difference.

In case of 1" sensors of aforementioned (~20 MP) cameras, does it add any significant value over conventionally designed BSI sensors? Are there any other pros, any cons?

Comment: I don't think chipworks has published anything publically on it recently.  But I suspect it's not as much of a port from small sensors as you think, which may give you an answer - IIRC it's one of the technologies that's given Nikon an edge in the high-iso stakes over the last few years.

Comment: OK, thanks! So **stacked** BSI CMOS sensors have already been used by Nikon thus giving them so great SNR results at DxOMark? And Exmor RS is just a marketing name by Sony for the same idea (although possibly physically designed a bit differently)? Feel free to convert this into an answer if you're sure. I just wanted to know if Exmor RS is really such a big deal while making RX10 II camera cost almost 2 times more than its predecessor with Exmor R.

Comment: I was going to but I wouldn't want to do that without docs to back it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although [Imaging-Resource.com Comparometer](http://www.imaging-resource.com/IMCOMP/COMPS01.HTM) or other samples don't show any radical improvement in the image quality (even with high ISO values) and eyes of many users on discussion forums support that, there are other benefits.

The stacked CMOS Sensor in DSC-RX10 II allows shutter speed up to 1/32000s (rolling shutter), continuous drive at 14fps and high-speed video 960 fps @ 1080p.

For the complete list of changes, see [Side by Side comparison at DPReview.com](http://www.dpreview.com/products/compare/side-by-side?products=sony_dscrx10ii&products=sony_dscrx10).